# Want to retrieve SQlite data and set it to map markers[ForceClose]

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an SQLite DB that's storing all coordinates + description to show them when taping on markers. I'm using this code to retreive all descriptions:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
            db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
           String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};
            Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns,
             null, null, null, null, null, null);
             cur.moveToFirst();
             while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Description"));

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
                dialog.setMessage(description);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

                cur.moveToNext();
             }
             cur.close();
             db.close();

            return true;
```

However, i'm having a weird problem that indicates that i'm not having Description column and i'm pretty sure that i have it.

```
08-23 02:45:02.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Description: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM table_coordonnées
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1220)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1107)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1065)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at carburant.android.com.Geo$ItemizedOverlayPerso.onTap(Geo.java:239)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:346)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:506)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:628)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-23 02:45:02.890: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be the problem please?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: "no such column: Description" looks of interest.

Comment: @pst: The strange thing that i'm having it, with capital D :\

Comment: Does the problem exist if the table name is plain-ASCII? (Not sure if there might be an internationalization issue.)

Comment: @pst: I thing that i have now w conflict with tables, i renamed tabel name to coordonnees and i have this: `no such table: table_coordonnees: , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_coordonnees(Latitude, Description, Longitude) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
` Perhaps the problem is to all delete(wipe all data with Database, preferences...). How doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your create statements and queries. I would use lower case everywhere. In an edit you write coordoonnees and table_coordoonnees. Both don't match.

SQLites error messages are very helpful always. If SQLite tells you about a missing table or column this item is definetely missing or mis-spelled.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "no such column: Description" and so you have to check your database once and also you are going in a wrong direction.

You are fetching co-ordinates in `onTap()` method and after getting cursor you are fetching loop and in loop you have write a code for display dialog.

So `your code will give you description of only last record.`

You have to create array of description for all co-ordinates and then in `onTap(int index)`  you have to get co-ordinates `using index variable of onTap(int index) method`